# Hibernate - Is there a possibility to wait with createEntityManager for a free connection

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm using the `EntityManagerFactory` from Hibernate and have a connectionPoolSize of 20. Now I have some larger queries (t> 30 min) that take up my pool completely. When I start a new query (with getEntityManager) I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available!
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
```

Are there any comfort features that put my thread to sleep until a connection is available?

I only use standard functions:

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager () {
return emFactory.createEntityManager ();
}
```

The Creation of my EntityManagerFactory:

```
public static void createEntityManagerFactory(String hostname, Integer port, String driver,
  String database, boolean validate, int maxConnections, Properties properties) {

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:" + driver + ":thin:@" + hostname + ":" + port + ":" + database);
props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", properties.getProperty("user")); 
props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", properties.getProperty("password"));
props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");

emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, props);
```

}

My persistence.xml contains:

```
<property name="connection.pool_size" value="20" />
```

I read about C3P0 settings, could they help me?

-- UPDATE -- I had some problems with C3P0 (for example: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM even with a small number of maximum connection pool size), that I didnt have with hibernate vanilla.  --
Configuration c3p0

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value ="2"/> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value ="10"/> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value ="2"/> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value ="100"/> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value ="3600"/>
```

Comment: Do you want to configure C3p0?

Comment: I can not judge, I just inform myself about it. Would it solve my problem?

Comment: Mh, I don't know, but with C3P0 is possible reuse a connection and not click and reopen it, surely it would be a small step in importing it into the project

Comment: i had some problems with C3P0 (for example: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM even with a small number of maximum connection pool size), that I didnt have with hibernate vanilla. Now im testing `Hikari`which looks promising at first glance. It looks like my original problem is solved, but I still can not say how stable hikari is or if it brings with it other problems.

Comment: how do you have configuration C3p0? can you post the code please?

Comment: i tried much, this is my last between standing: 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value ="2"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value ="10"/> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value ="2"/> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value ="100"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value ="3600"/>

Comment: Please delete your comment I have to add your configuration inside your question, but, I don't know if you work, the configuration hibernate is inside your code or inside your XML? if the code is inside the your code I think is more better insert configuration c3p0 inside your code, so the your configuration is  `props.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_sizehibernate.c3p0.min_size", 2);`

Comment: also inside your configuration, I would this propriety `hibernate.c3p0.min_statements`

Comment: Im holding the definitions in the persistence.xml 
and I see in the connection setup that these are taken over

Comment: I’m not sure but if the hibernate used the intern c3p0 (is not necessary import c3p0 jar) the configuration must be inside the unique configuration, this is only my idea, try to add all configuration inside your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved this problem with using [hikaricp](/questions/tagged/hikaricp) for connection pooling.